# Разница всех чисел друг с другом

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица:

```
id | number
----------
1  | 5
2  | 3
3  | 7 
4  | 1
5  | 6
6  | 3
7  | 7
```

Как в столбце Number найти разницу первой строки со всеми остальными и также найти разницу всех остальных строк со всеми остальными и вывести допустим это в отдельный столбец.

Comment: что такое "разница всех остальных строк со всеми остальными"? вы понимаете, что там столько разниц, сколько строк? Как должен выглядеть результат?

Comment: Да, понимаю, думаю что в результате должно сформироваться что-то вроде такого:
`1 |  2               
1 |  -2              
1 |  4               
1 |  -1              
1 |  2               
1 |  -2              
2 |  -4              
2 |  2               
2 |  -3              
...`
И да, разницу можно не считать если уже посчитана в предыдущий раз между двумя этими числами. Тоесть по сути вконце только посчитается между 6 и 7

Comment: Добавляйте уточнения в тело вопроса (кнопка "править")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
select f.id, f.number - s.number
from mytable f
  join mytable s on (f.id < s.id)
```